# What is the best Jenkins dashboard plugin that displays all results?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cucumber, jenkins-plugins

Can someone point out a plugin that can aggregate all results from all jobs into one uniform Pass/Fail/Skipped dashboard?

I am currently using the dashboard view in jenkins that shows me grids, pie charts and test trends using Junit results. [image: Jenkins Dashborad view with only Junit]

I am now using Calabash and would like to publish the Cucumber reports to the same dashboard.
[image: Cucumber reports in its own dashboard view]

If someone can point me out to a dashboard that can consume all formats so I can have a centralized reporting page I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Dashing would be an ideal choice since it is highly customisable. 
Check it out from http://dashing.io
There are plenty 3rd party libs that does integration with jenkins and uses dashing in github as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating influxdb with jenkins.

Why influxdb?

- Open source
- Its time series database
- Existing jenkins plugin
- Easier to build query using GUI, no need to learn flux query to
  get required data
- Existing dashboard templates
- Easier to connect to Grafana to
  visualize, monitor data and create dashboards

Plugin Path: https://plugins.jenkins.io/influxdb/